# Tikz and enlarging part of the draw.

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I plotted a number of curves on the same figure using tikzpicture. but i am having a problem with enlarging part of the curves on the same figure. I searched for that and i found something similar on this website http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/difference-quotient/

but, i tried everything and it is not working, does anyone know anything i can do to fix the problem?

Comment: maybe it should be made clear what isn't working?

Comment: @Leo: As I understand the problem, user891 has the current stable TikZ version installed, but the linked example needs a development version.

Answer (score 4):

See "48 Spy Library: Magnifying Parts of Picutres" in the tikz manual, which contains two short examples on using this library.

But you will need to install the devel version of tikz/pgf. The stable release of tikz/pgf 2.0 (which is included in TeX live) is a bit dated. Meanwhile the devel version has moved forward incorporating bug fixes and new libraries. You can get the devel version by either of the following methods.

```
http://www.texample.net/tikz/builds/ (pre-packaged and hence recommended)
```

or

```
cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/pgf co -P pgf
```

Comment: Could you expand on your answer? "Look at the manual in CVS" is not particularly useful...

Comment: Thank you! It should be noted that the current stable TikZ version (which is contained in the various TeX distributions) is rather old and the up-to-date development version has some nice improvements, one of which is used in the linked example.

Comment: I have tried to urge a bug-fix release for TL2009 and nobody seems to care. I guess people just have to continue installing the devel version if they want new features.